# Two way data binding in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm developing a jQuery Backbone.js web application.
As it is in Adobe Flex, I have implemented 2 way data binding in my app for
input elements/widgets.
So, every input element/widget knows its corresponding model and model attribute name.
When the user hits tab or enter, the field value is automatically given to the model.

```
container.model.set(this.attrName, this.value, options); // command 1
```

In the other direction, when the model gets updated from the backend, the view of the
input element/widget should automatically get
 updated:

```
container.model.bind("change:"+ this.attrName, this.updateView, this); // command 2
```

The problem is:
When the user hits enter and the model is automatically updated, also the "change:abc" is
triggered and this.updateView is called, not only when a new model comes from the
backend.

My solution until now was to pass an option "source: gui" when setting the model value when the user pressed enter (command 1), and to check for that in my updateView method. But I am not content with this solution anymore.

Does anybody have a better solution?
Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Update:
When the option silent: true is passed, the validate method of the model is not called, so 
that does not help. See Backbone.js source 0.9.2:

```
_validate: function(attrs, options) {
  if (options.silent || !this.validate) return true;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Backbone.js site:

> A "change" event will be triggered, unless {silent: true} is passed as an option

```
options.silent = true;
container.model.set(this.attrName, this.value, options);
```

**Update:**
You added a new comment to your question, so I just complemented my answer to fix the new use case(validation flow) that you mentioned:

```
var ExtendedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    uiChange : false,
    uiSet: function (attributes, options, optional) {
        this.uiChange = true;
        this.set(attributes, options, optional);
        this.uiChange = false;
    }
});

var MyModel = ExtendedModel.extend({
});

var model = new MyModel();
model.on('change:name', function(){
  console.log('this.uiChange: ', this.uiChange);
});

//simulates the server side set
model.set({name:'hello'});

//simulates the ui side set you must use it to set from UI
model.uiSet({name:'hello2'});
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. But with this option, "validate" is not called. So it does not help me.

Answer (score 7):

Two-way binding just means that:

1. When properties in the model get updated, so does the UI.
2. When UI elements get updated, the changes get propagated back to the
   model.

Backbone doesn't have a "baked-in" implementation of 2 option (although you can certainly do it using event listeners)

In Backbone, we can easily achieve option 1 by binding a view's "render" method to its model's "change" event. To achieve option 2, you need to also add a change listener to the input element, and call model.set in the handler.

check (jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/Xm5eH/16)jsfiddle example with two-way binding set up in Backbone.

Answer (score 2):

`Backbone.ModelBinder`plugin works great for providing Two-way data binding between your Backbone Views and Models. I wrote a blog post covering some essential features of this plugin Here is the direct link: http://niki4810.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/new-post/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see what the bare bones code would be to have two-way binding with Backbone.js.  This is what I came up with:

```
var TwoWayBoundView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, this.options);
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
        this.render();
    },

    events: {
        "change input,textarea,select": "update"
    },

    // input updated
    update: function(e) {
        this.model.set(e.currentTarget.id, $(e.currentTarget).val());
    },

    // model updated...re-render
    render: function(e) {
        if (e){
            var id = Object.keys(e.changed)[0];
            $('#'+id).val(e.changed[id]);
        }
        else{
            _.each(this.model.attributes, function(value, key){
                $('#'+key).val(value);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And the usage:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({ prop1: "uno 1", prop2: "dos 2", prop3: "3" });
var view = new TwoWayBoundView({ 
    el: "#myContainer",
    model: model
});
```

Here's a jsbin for it: http://jsbin.com/guvusal/edit?html,js,console,output

I've used libraries that do this, such as Epoxy.js (only 11k minified).  And there are several others besides, which I would recommend long before using the proof of concept code above.

I would be interested in potential pitfalls and improvements that could be made with the TwoWayBoundView class above (but ***nothing*** beyond basic two-way binding please!  i.e. I'm ***not*** looking for more features to add.)